# API giving ship positions worldwide

Tags: data-request, api, transportation, ais

[ShipAIS](http://www.shipais.com/showship.php?map=folkstone&mmsi=256933000) has a great database and web interface showing what ships are in a particular area:

[image: shipAIS]

Unfortunately, it is limited to North Europe.

Is there a similar database for ships in the whole world?

- Free unlimited API availability strongly preferred
- Ideally open data, reusable on Wikimedia projects

Answer (score 15):

I've used [MarineTraffic.com](http://www.marinetraffic.com/) for finding details about yachts and ships I've seen in ports. It's a really cool website.

[image]

They also have an [API](http://www.marinetraffic.com/p/api-services), **but, unfortunately, there is no free access.**

---

There is an API option from [FleetMon](https://www.fleetmon.com/faq/public_api) that is mostly-free:

> The FleetMon Public API lets software developers create great software apps that are able to display ship positions and master data, port calls, weather conditions, ports and much more. Developers get a powerful tool to connect their software to the FleetMon.com Vessel Database, enabling them to develop own services as well as integrate with existing IT systems and logistics solutions.

This would be a better option, although I don't know how complete their DB is.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

aprs.fi has an api: https://aprs.fi/page/api

however, of late it has been slow to update the vessel i wanted to track, often weeks with no updates. :(

Comment: yes, it probably depends on the vessel you want to track.  it had been working really well for me in the past.