# Identifying a superyacht from date and location

Tags: data-request, database, oceanographic, location, ais

A while ago, while vacationing in a sunny island in the Mediterranean, I saw a beautiful superyacht anchored off a bay. I would like to know the name of this yacht and who designed it.

I do not know if it is required that yachts of this size turn their [AIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_identification_system) transceivers on.

Given the **latitude** and **longitude** of some reference point in this bay, a **radius** and a **date**, is it possible to find out a list of all vessels that were inside the circle centered at the given reference point and with the given radius on the given date?

---

Related:

- [API giving ship positions worldwide](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4139/12650)
- [Free source of AIS data (API)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/15329/12650)